# Xmpp String utils crashes the app frequently

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, xmpp, ejabberd, smack

I have developed chat application using Smack 4.1 library which uses ejabberd server for chatting.

**All the chat works properly but sometime app gets crashed with below error,unable to understand why this happen frequently?**

Below error gets from crashlytics:-

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.indexOf(int)' on a null object reference
       at org.jxmpp.util.XmppStringUtils.parseBareJid(XmppStringUtils.java:117)
       at org.jivesoftware.smack.roster.Roster$RosterPushListener.handleIQRequest(Roster.java:1386)
       at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection$2.run(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:1051)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Below code is used for connecting and login to ejabberd:-

```
   XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
    config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
    config.setServiceName(Constants.HOST);
    config.setPort(Constants.PORT);
    config.setHost(Constants.HOST);
    config.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
    config.setSendPresence(true);
    config.setUsernameAndPassword(strUsername + "@" + Constants.HOST, strPassword);


    SASLAuthentication.blacklistSASLMechanism("SCRAM-SHA-1");
    SASLAuthentication.blacklistSASLMechanism("DIGEST-MD5");
    SASLAuthentication.unBlacklistSASLMechanism("PLAIN");
    objXmpptcpConnection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config.build());
    objXmpptcpConnection.setUseStreamManagement(true);
    objXmpptcpConnection.setUseStreamManagementResumption(true);
    try {
        objXmpptcpConnection.connect();
        System.out.println("Connected to===>" + objXmpptcpConnection.getHost());
        objXmpptcpConnection.login();

    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (SmackException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Is there any setting which I missed it or Please suggest solution to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I will need to look at the code to see whats happening exactly. But from you stack trace it looks like your when someone is added to your buddy list, XMPP lib expects the person's JID in the callback. But you are passing it null and hence the crash.

Try disabling Roster related XMPP and see if the crash persists.

Comment: I am not using any functionality related with roster.So,Is there any setting to Off the Roster functionality of Smack